# How precise must corner reflectors be to render satellite megaconstellations effectively invisible to astronomers?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, reflection, diffraction

With [the emerging environmental concerns over light pollution from satellite megaconstellations](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/spacex-starlink-mega-constellation-faces-fresh-legal-challenge/), getting a quantitative estimate of the magnitudes of various approaches to minimizing the pollution becomes salient.  For instance, in the aforelinked article, appears this assertion about the Starlink constellation:

> To put them in the range of ‘no concern,’ they would need to be at
> least 100 times dimmer,” says Richard Green of the University of
> Arizona, who is chairing a SATCON2 group investigating policy issues
> surrounding mega constellations. “That’s moving beyond the range of
> physical possibility.”

Is it?  Keep in mind that SpaceX is (along with others) intent on lowering the cost of access to low Earth orbit dramatically -- quite possibly by more than a factor of 10.

One seemingly obvious potential is to use radio-transparent, very precise optical corner reflectors to return light to its point of origin.  Although this does not deal with light sources near astronomical observatories, there are typically very few such sources.   On moonless nights there should be very little light coming back to the observatory from a given satellite.

So how precise must these corner reflectors be to reach Green's "100 times dimmer" criterion?  Or am I missing something that renders the idea unworkable even in principle?

Comment: "Light sources near astronomical observatories" are not the problem; the problem is *sunlight* reflecting off the spacecraft.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking a bit too hard :).  If you can get some data on the BRDF (bidirectional reflectance distribution function) for typical corner cubes, *and* the incident power on the cube,  you'll know at what angle to the cube's optic axis you want your observatory to be to get less than X watts (or photons/sec) within your 'scope's field of view.

However, there's no way to make the entire satellite a retroreflector.  So you really need to grab data on the satellite's  "optical cross-section" (analogous to the well-known RCS , radar cross-section) value, which will easily allow you to calculate the fractional backscatter in your direction.